# How do I display the thread / child process count of a process in top?

Tags: top, thread

I know there is a one-line-per-thread view (-H), but the particular threads are not grouped by master process. In fact, I would be completely satisfied with the sole thread count per process (= how many sub-threads does some process create?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [top man page](https://manpages.debian.org/procps/top.1) describes the field you're looking for:

> 50. nTH  --  Number of Threads
>       The number of threads associated with a process.

(number above would probably change depending on OS and *top* version).

Interactively, you can use the <kbd>f</kbd> (Fields Management) key, then move down to `nTH`, activate it with <kbd>space</kbd>, select it for column display order change with <kbd>→</kbd>, move it up with <kbd>↑</kbd>, and validate with <kbd>esc</kbd>. If you're satisfied with the result, you can finally save it in `~/.toprc` with <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>, so you won't have to do this again.

I'm not sure if there's an other method (eg command line) to toggle this field.

Comment: Yes, I didn't know the trick with the fields management yet. But now it works. Thank you!